# linewidth based on shapefile attribute for geopandas, python

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I would like to plot a `shapefile` using geopandas. I would like to have the thickness of the lines in accordance with an attribute in the `shapefile`. I am using the following command for that:

```py
shp_sub.plot(column='Case1_2', cmap='BuGn', figsize=(5,5), linewidth=shp_sub['Case1_2'], edgecolor='0.8', vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

This means that the thickness and the colour code should match each other.

I have tried this:

```py
shp_sub.plot(column='Case1_2', cmap='BuGn', figsize=(5,5), linewidth=1, edgecolor='0.8', vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

[image: Image 1]

When I try this, I don't get the one-to-one.

```py
shp_sub.plot(column='Case1_2', cmap='BuGn', figsize=(5,5), linewidth=shp_sub['Case1_2'], edgecolor='0.8', vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your 'Case1_2' attribute is not numeric or not numeric within a range that changes the linewidth meaningfully. Linewidths between 0 and ~15 are probably all you are interested in plotting. If you create a new attribute that is numeric based (e.g., based on stream order), then using the column values to set linewidth should work.

```
shp_sub['order'] = 1. # best to be numeric, not a geometry
shp_sub['order'].iloc[10] = 4. # change the value of one of the attributes
shp_sub.plot(column='Case1_2', cmap='BuGn', figsize=(5,5),
             linewidth=shp_sub['order'], edgecolor='0.8', # edgecolor another column with data?
             vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

Or you can scale one of your existing columns to be within the range of useful linewidths:

```
import numpy as np
temp_array = shp_sub['Case1_2'].values
# Scale from 0 to 1
temp_array = (np.max(temp_array)-temp_array)/(np.max(temp_array)-np.min(temp_array))

max_width = 10 # set maximum line width to use

shp_sub['lw'] = max_width*temp_array
# and then plot with linewidth=shp_sub['lw']
```